# why have so many pass in varnish?

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have a varnish cache (version 4) with a backend that sometimes turns "slow". I use the health check to force varnish serve stale content from the cache when this backend is "slow" to not saturate it.

So mi backend is defined:

```
backend api {
    .host = "111.111.111.111";
    .port = "80";
    .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
    .probe = {
            .url = "/some/url";
            .expected_response = 200;
            .timeout = 80ms;
            .interval = 120s;
            .window = 1;
            .threshold = 1;
    }
```

}

```
backend apibackup {
    .host = "111.111.111.111";
    .port = "80";
    .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
    .probe = {
            .url = "/some/url";
            .expected_response = 200;
            .timeout = 80ms;
            .interval = 120s;
            .window = 1;
            .threshold = 1;
    }
```

}

And configure the grace mode:

```
sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl > 0s) {
            # A standard hit, deliver from cache
            return (deliver);
    }
    elsif (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
            if (obj.ttl + 30s > 0s) {
                    # page expired within a limited grace time and backend
                    # is healthy: deliver from cache while cache is updated
                    # asynchronous
                    return (deliver);
            } else {
                    # page expired too long ago - fetch from backend
                    return (fetch);
            }
    }
    else {
            if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
                    # backend is not healthy - provide the page from cache
                    # during full grace time set in vcl_backend_response
                    return (deliver);
            } else {
                    # page expired for the full grace time and backend is
                    # considered unhealthy - try to contact the backend
                    # anyway

                    return (fetch);
            }
    }
```

}

But only with this configuration, if the backend is sick and the object don't exists in the cache, varnish returns a 503 (and I want to fetch from backend). To avoid this behaviour, I must put the same conf in vcl_miss to force varnish fetch content from the "sick" backend:

```
sub vcl_miss{

    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
                    return (fetch);
            }
    else {
                    set req.backend_hint = apibackup;
                    return (fetch);
            }
```

}

This way, the result is as expected, when backend is slow, varnish serve stale content from cache and the responses times improve.

But, I discovered that now I have a lot more of "pass" request. Request that of course, varnish should caching (and before it did). Aprox *100 more. So I fixed a problem, but I created another.

The cookie is unset, both (in recv and in backend response), to force varnish to caching.

```
unset beresp.http.set-cookie;

unset req.http.Cookie;
```

So, my question is... Why I have a lot of passes requests? how i can to avoid then?

Answer (score 0):

> But only with this configuration, if the backend is sick and the
>   object don't exists in the cache, varnish returns a 503 (and I want to
>   fetch from backend). To avoid this behaviour, I must put the same conf
>   in vcl_miss to force varnish fetch content from the "sick" backend:
>
> ...

I think this assumption is wrong. That `vcl_miss` subroutine is equivalent to the built-in one; you're always executing a `return (fetch)`. Adding that code does not force Varnish to use a sick backend when grace content is not available. In fact, as far as I know, you cannot force Varnish to use a sick backend at all.

I've created a toy Varnish test case to show that using that code nothing changes. Varnish will never use a sick backend when grace content is not available and therefore it will send a 503 response to the client.

```
varnishtest ""

server s1 {
    rxreq
    expect req.url == "/1"
    txresp -body "foo"
} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    import std;

    sub vcl_hit {
        if (obj.ttl > 0s) {
            return (deliver);
        }
        elsif (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
            return (deliver);
        }
        else {
            if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
                return (deliver);
            } else {
                return (fetch);
            }
        }
    }

    # XXX: nonsense subroutine equivalent to the build-in one just to show this
    # doesn't force Varnish to fetch contents from sick backends.
    sub vcl_miss{
        if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
            return (fetch);
        } else {
            return (fetch);
        }
    }

    sub vcl_backend_response {
        set beresp.ttl = 1s;
        set beresp.grace = 1s;
    }
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.bodylen == 3
} -run

varnish v1 -cliok "backend.set_health s1 sick"

delay 1.5

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.bodylen == 3
} -run

delay 1.0

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 503

    txreq -url "/2"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 503
} -run
```

**Updated test case:**

```
varnishtest ""

server s1 {
    rxreq
    expect req.url == "/1"
    txresp -body "foo"

    rxreq
    expect req.url == "/1"
    txresp -body "foobar"

    rxreq
    expect req.url == "/2"
    txresp -body "hello"
} -start

varnish v1 -vcl {
    import std;

    backend default {
        .host = "${s1_addr}";
        .port = "${s1_port}";
    }

    backend backup {
        .host = "${s1_addr}";
        .port = "${s1_port}";
    }

    sub vcl_hit {
        if (obj.ttl > 0s) {
            return (deliver);
        }
        elsif (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
            return (deliver);
        }
        else {
            if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
                return (deliver);
            } else {
                return (fetch);
            }
        }
    }

    sub vcl_miss{
        if (!std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
            set req.backend_hint = backup;
        }
        return (fetch);
    }

    sub vcl_backend_response {
        set beresp.ttl = 1s;
        set beresp.grace = 1s;
    }
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.bodylen == 3
} -run

varnish v1 -cliok "backend.set_health default sick"

delay 1.5

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.bodylen == 3
} -run

delay 1.0

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.bodylen == 6

    txreq -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.bodylen == 6

    txreq -url "/2"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.bodylen == 5
} -run

varnish v1 -expect cache_hit == 2
varnish v1 -expect cache_hitpass == 0
```

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I forgot a little big detail. I have an alternative backend (but is the same) to force varnish to fetch the content.

Comment: Thanks! That detail was very important :) I've adjusted the test case to reflect your set up and it works as expected. I mean, contents are fetched from the backup backend and the ``cache_hitpass`` counter is not increasing. How are you measuring those 'pass' requests?